# Extracting data from a mongo collection

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, pymongo

I'm collecting real-time tweets and storing into a collection I now want to extract the information from a record in the collection:

```
  "place" : { "country_code" : "US", "url" : "http://api.twitter.com/1/geo   /id/01fbe706f872cb32.json", "country" : "United States", "place_type" : "city",  "bounding_box" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [  [ [     -77.119759,      38.791645 ],   [   -76.909393,     38.791645 ],    [   -76.909393,     38.995548  ],   [   -77.119759,     38.995548 ] ] ] }, "full_name" : "Washington, DC",  "attributes" : { }, "id" : "01fbe706f872cb32", "name" : "Washington" }
```

I just want the coordiante information, so using pymongo I try to do:

```
 cursor = coll.find({"place.bounding_box.type" : "Polygon"},{"coordinates" : 1}, tailable = True, timeout = False)
```

But this doesn't return the coordinates where the bounding box is the key.

How could I get this data returned?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do this

```
cursor = coll.find({"place.bounding_box.type" : "Polygon"}, {"place.bounding_box.coordinates" : 1})
```

This will return data in the format:

```
>> cursor.next()
"place" : {"bounding_box" : { "coordinates" : [  [ [     -77.119759,      38.791645 ],   [   -76.909393,     38.791645 ],    [   -76.909393,     38.995548  ],   [   -77.119759,     38.995548 ] ] ]}
```

So to get the data you seem to want:

```
for doc in cursor:
    print doc["place"]["bounding_box"]["coordinates"]
```

Comment: Thanks that works..... so I needed to have also done: {"place.bounding_box.coordinates" : 1}, rather than just {"coordinates" : 1}.